# "Holding" a Data Map in memory

Tags: multithreading, haskell, memory-management, haskell-snap-framework

I have three data structures defined as such, where `S`, `LL`, `M`, and `Object`, represent `Set`, `ListLike`, `Map`, and `ByteString`, respectively:

```
nouns :: IO [Object]
nouns = liftM LL.words $ B.readFile "nounlist.txt"

obj :: IO ObjectSet
obj =  liftM S.fromList nouns

actions :: IO ActionMap
actions = do
  n <- nouns
  let l = foldl' (\z x -> (x,Sell):(x,Create):z) [] n
  return $ M.fromList $
    (\(x,y) -> ((x, Verb y []), Out (Verb y []) x)) <$> l
```

Now I have one function that binds the unevaluated Set and Map to variables `a` and `o`. Once it enters `query`, an infinite loop of queries are accepted via user-input and processed. Appropriate responses are generated via lookups.

```
process :: IO ()
process = do
  a <- actions
  o <- obj
  forever $ query "" a o
```

Keeping in mind that my Map is composed of 300,000+ key-value pairs: The initial temporal overhead of the first evaluation when the first query is called is between approximately 3-5 seconds, on my computer; this is fine and completely expected. Every other subsequent call is snappy and responsive, just the way I want it. However, this is only so because I am running this code as a standalone executable and have the luxury of staying within the `IO ()` of `process`. If I were to turn this code (and the rest of the accompanying code not listed) into a library to interface with say .. a *Snap Framework Web Application*, I wouldn't necessarily have this luxury. Essentially what I am trying to say is: If I were to remove the `forever` from `process` then the evaluated Map and Set would surely get garbage-collected. Indeed this is what happens when I call the function from a Snap Application (I can't keep `forever` because it will block the Snap Application). Every subsequent call from the Snap Application will have the same 3-5 second overhead because it re-evaluates the data structures in question.

---

**My Question:**

Is there an easy way to hold the Map and Set in memory so that every subsequent lookup is fast? One Idea I came up with was to run a thread that sleeps and maintains storage for the Map and Set. However, this definitely seems like overkill to me. What am I overlooking? Thank you for bearing with my long-winded explanation.

**Note: I'm not necessarily looking for code answers, moreso suggestions, advice, etc.**

Comment: How about using a top level `IORef` to store `actions`?

Comment: @user2407038 TBH, I have never used or even read about an `IORef` before. If you are suggesting that this would be a way to remedy my memory issues, then I will give the topic a perusal.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Snap`, but why not evaluate `nouns` and `obj` during the initialization of your application, then pass those (pure) values to `process :: [Object] -> [ObjectSet] -> IO ()`. This will ensure those values are only evaluated once.

Comment: @cdk will be looking into that, I have experimented with similar trials on the `Snap` end, Unfortunately I am in the midst of learning Snap as well \=. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Does snap repeatedly run it for you?

Comment: @PyRulez No, I just placed a route inside my Snap initializer, and when user submits a form to my web application, it just gets handled as a command to be processed as an action (or failure) by my back-end function. So no, Snap does not repeatedly run it, it gets called as a single instance when a user makes a "request."

Comment: @user2407038 May I ask: How does using an `IORef` at the top-level differ from my top-level data structures that I have delcared in my explanation? From what I've (just recently) read about IORefs, I gather that they are references to data with mutable state. I don't really need to mutate anything, but perhaps I am overlooking something grander you are trying to imply? Does introducing my data in the form of an `IORef` with mutable state at the top-level imply that I will have strict data read into memory, relatively protected from GC?

Comment: @user2407038, I tried using IORef at top level, it made no difference unfortunately. I guess the lazy nature of Haskell is really taking over.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can evaluate `obj` and `actions` only once during snaplet initialization and store result in snaplet's state.

```
data SnapApp = SnapApp
    { objectSet :: ObjectSet
    , actionMap :: ActionMap
    }

appInit :: SnapletInit SnapApp SnapApp
appInit = makeSnaplet ... $ do
    ... 
    a <- liftIO actions
    o <- liftIO obj
    return $ SnapApp o a
```

Now you can access them from snap's `Handler`:

```
someUrlHandler :: Handler SnapApp SnapApp
someUrlHandler = do
  a <- gets actionMap
  o <- gets objectMap
  res <- query a o
  ...
```

This guarantees that `actions` and `obj` will be evaluated only once.

Comment: Your answer was clearly the most incisive and it worked like a charm. There was little to no reconstruction involved, and I was able to work within Snap's framework. Performance is restored, and you have a really cool looking avatar by the way. Thank you. +1 and check.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding avatar, it was made from some Wassily Kandinsky's paintings: https://www.google.com/search?q=kandinsky&tbm=isch

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I was think of doing with `IORef`:

```
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe 
import Control.Monad 

val_ :: IORef (Maybe Integer)
val_ = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef Nothing

val :: IO Integer
val = do 
  v <- readIORef val_
  case v of 
    Just v' -> return v' 
    Nothing -> do
           v' <- readFile "large.txt" 
           -- replace this part with your actual computation
           let l = sum $ map (fromIntegral . fromEnum) v' 
           writeIORef val_ $ Just l
           return l 

main = do 
  writeFile "large.txt" (replicate (10^7) '0')
  putStrLn "reading"
  replicateM_ 10 (val >>= print)
```

You ensure that the time consuming operation is only ever evaluated once. When you execute `val` the first time, it will write the value to the `IORef` and retrieve it from there every subsequent time. When I ran `main`, it will take a few seconds to print the number the first time and no time at all afterwards.

You need to have `unsafePerformIO` because `IORef x` can't be garbage collected but `IO (IORef x)` will be.

Keep in mind that writing to the `IORef` does not evaluate anything, it will be evaluated the first time it is used, even if you call `val` earlier.

The simpler solution is probably to use monad transformers. You didn't provide an example of where in your snap program this table will be used, so I can't really give a satisfactory example.

Comment: Not how I really envisioned solving the problem; however, you did inform me about some IORef characteristics and how they work with GC. This was something I was curious about anyway. +1

Answer (score 1):

I do believe `TVar` could do it.

```
import Control.Concurrent.Concurrent

intial=do
    objects <- newTVarIO Nothing
    --I didn't understand your example code well, bear with me (and fix this.)
    queryMachine <- mkQueryMachine objects
    return queryMachine

queryMachine objects=QueryMachine $ do
    objects''' <- atomically $ do
        objects' <- readTVar objects
        case objects' of
            Nothing -> do
                let objects'' = objectsMaker
                writeTVar objects $ Just objects''
                return objects''
            Just objects'' -> return objects''

    profitFrom objects'''
```

Adapt to your own needs.

**Explanation**

TVar is a mutable variable in the STM monad. STM is quite thread safe. The `atomically` converts it to an IO action. For multiple types of things you are doing this for, create separate STM actions, and call `atomically` on each one. That is because you want `atomically` blocks to be small, so that the locks they take don't take too many "locks" (sort of.) The above code can be improved by, say, having a TSem from Control.Concurrent.STM.TSem, that would make sure only one thread would try calculating it, in case two requests come in at the same time.

Comment: Will give a look into your concurrent solution as soon as possible. Thanks for your input @PyRulez.

Comment: I actually haven't tried this yet; is there way to possibly do this _without_ threads? As stated above, I was thinking of a thread-type solution, but I thought it would be overkill, simple for storing objects. I just want to make sure I try every possible reasonable solution before getting thread-happy.

Comment: Although not how I would like to address the issue, I did bring up threading, and you did inform me about some important aspects related to threading. +1

Comment: I think threads are inherit to web servers. It is not this code with the forks.

Comment: You're right, it is important with web servers. You are also right in that you don't appear to make any calls to `forkIO` in your pseudocode. I suppose I was a little distracted by the import of the `Concurrent` library, but yes you are technically right @PyRulez, sorry about that.